# Caching wrapper for digest computation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cache, wrapper

I need to review this code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// REVIEW
public abstract class Digest {
    private Map<String, byte[]> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public byte[] digest(String input) {
        byte[] result = cache.get(input);
        if (result == null) {
            synchronized (cache) {
                result = cache.get(input);
                if (result == null) {
                    result = doDigest(input);
                    cache.put(input, result);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract byte[] doDigest(String input);
}
```

1. Should I mark `cache` as volatile ?
   I have doubts because we use `cashe.get` in method body instead of direct `cashe`
2. Would it make sense to replace the map with `ConcurrentHashMap`?
3. Is there way to fix code without replacing map implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Volatile won't do anything here, as this basically only affects the reference to the map, not the contents of the map.

As for ConcurrentHashMap (as opposed to explicit synchronizing I suppose): this depends. If you want to make absolutely sure that no digest is ever computed twice, stick to your approach. If you just want general concurrency, but can accept that *eventually* in race-conditions, digest is called twice for the same input (sidenote: I suppose digest is deterministic, so that two calls with the same input yield the same result), you may simply repace the map with a ConcurrentHashMap and the whole method with:

```
return cache.computeIfAbsent(input, this::doDigest);
```

Comment: 1.I believe that this computeIfAbsent will execute doDigest only once. 2. Is there way to fix this code without change map implementation?

Comment: If you are in a multithreaded environment, computeIfAbsent may call the computation twice, if a second thread requests the same data before the first thread has completed the computation. Also, for multithreaded caching, you'll have to synchronize / block *somewhere*. Generally, you are mostly better off when you leave this to the standard library than implementing this yourself.

Comment: please provide proov about twice computation. computeIfAbsent uses synchronize inside

Comment: The synchronization is on the new node which in turn can be created by the unsafe class. This is really hard to read and I may be mistaken here, but I *think* that this may be different node objects for concurrent calls with the same keys. However, as this is *your* problem, I suggest you simply write some test code to verify or proof me wrong. And *if* I really misunderstood the code, this is even better as it solves your problem completly with a single line of code. :)

Comment: Ok, but I really want to know how to solve problem without CHM. I just want to know it in educational purposes.

Comment: Then the answer boils down to: do it the way you already do, and volatile won't change anything.

Comment: I believe that it is wrong that I can read and write map in parallel

Comment: You don't read and write in parallel: you first read (twice) and then write. As the second read and the write are in a synchronized block, ther won't be any problems.

Comment: it is possible if you have several threads which execute digest method in parallel

Comment: Please look up the meaning of a synchronized block. Nevertheless, this is leaving the scope of the original quesiton as I understood it - quitting here.

Comment: thread1 can execute  **byte[] result = cache.get(input)** (this code outside the  sync block) and thread2 can do **cache.put(input, result)** at the same moment